Children's TV show with magic mirror where animated scenes happened in the mirror
I'm trying to identify an 80's -early 90's children's show I had on VHS.
The things I remember about this show are: 

Mirror - A magic mirror was an element to the story. 
Someone would "find" the mirror (I remember a man rowing in a pond and finding it in the reeds). Then they set the scene to see the story in the mirror.
Animated scenes - I can only recall 2 of these "mirror stories"
Both felt like they had non-English bases. In one people were dancing around a fire on the beach. The story had a sad tone. In another black shadow creatures called hobbyharves(?) tip toes around. They stole children and the story had a dark/scary feel.

I was born in '85 and probably watched in about 88-93.
 Did you watch this or know this? Please let me know!

So the scenes outside the mirror are live action footage? I remember some movie, it had a boy who's transformed into a fish (I think through a mirror), but I simply can't remember its name...

The Magic Mirror - Fairy Tales (thanks, generic names!). Someone on YA! found it here, the "shadow men" are called Hobyahs (one of the story titles).
